# Trying to find amount of CPU cores in batch file

Tags: loops, for-loop, batch-file, cpu

Below is working code I have been using but as you can see it uses the environment variable for amount of processors which is usually cores * 2 on most computers these days. Is there a way I can do something similar to base my loop on the amount of cores in the cpu and/or how can I edit my loop to divide the amount of processors by 2?

```
set loopcount=%NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS%
:loop
START "Batch Script" MyProgram.exe
set /a loopcount=loopcount-1
if %loopcount%==0 goto exitloop
goto loop
:exitloop
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any question that amounts to "how can I find out information about my computer?", the answer is always to use `wmic`.

```
for /F "delims=" %%A in ('wmic cpu get NumberOfCores /format:value ^| find "NumberOfCores"') do set %%A
for /L %%A in (1,1,%NumberOfCores%) do start "Batch Script" MyProgram.exe
```

---

Of course, if you're looking for a way to do math in batch, just use `set /a`.

```
set /a loopcount=%NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS%/2
```

Comment: `wmic cpu get NumberOfCores` gives the number of physical cores, so `%NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS%/2` returns just half of that

Comment: @phuclv - The question was to find the number of cores, so I gave two ways to do that, since `%NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS%` refers to the number of logical processors, not the number of physical processors.

Comment: ah yes I didn't read the question carefully. But dividing by 2 won't solve the OP's problem. What if some CPUs in the future have more than threads per core? Intel Xeon Phi has 4 threads/core and PPC even has CPUs with 8 threads/core. So the only correct way is `wmic cpu get NumberOfCores`

Comment: I would be inclined to create both the `%Cores%` and `%Loops%` variables at once: `For /F "Tokens=2Delims==" %%G In ('WMIC CPU Get NumberOfCores /Value')Do Set /A Cores=%%G,Loops=Cores/2 2>NUL`

Comment: Thank you for letting me know about wmic. I also didn't know about the /a to do math. First time creating a batch file but now I know